# Alpha animation bug on button

Tags: android, animation, button, touch, alpha

I have animations that fade in a Button (alpha from 0 to 1) and fade out a button (alpha from 1 to 0). This part is all working fine. Button A triggers the fade in of Button B. Button B triggers the fade out of itself.

Button B totally covers up Button A. The idea is that Button B contains an image that is used like an information popup. Button A is touched and Button B fades in on top. When Button B is touched it fades itself out again.

Initially, Button B's visibility is set INVISIBLE and when the fade in animation is complete, it is set to VISIBLE. When Button B is clicked it fades out and then I set the visibility to INVISIBLE.

The problem is that after Button B has faded out, and it is set INVISIBLE, it is still clickable and even though it is not visible, and touches are not received by Button A.

I have tried removing Button B from the parent and re-adding it after the animation is completed, and this allows for touches to reach Button A, but only once. After that button B is not longer touchable.

Comment: I don't see a question here at all. Do you have one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting button to invisible, use:

```
buttonB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

in addition you can also set:

```
buttonB.setClickable(false);
```

Regards.

Comment: Great idea, but buttonB is still capturing the events when using GONE. I moved buttonB so that it is only covering half of ButtonA. I know buttonB is capturing the events because it is working properly when I click on the uncovered part of A. I check it in the debugger to make sure.

Comment: Tha's weird ... I'm using GONE with one animation in my app, and the button don't capture the `onClick()`. The only difference is that I have a group of buttons inside a layout, and I set the layout to GONE instead of individual buttons. Which event are you capturing?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option to avoid a button capturing the tap.

Comment: this.animateAlphaButton =(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.animateAlpha);
    this.animateAlphaButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.animateAlphaButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I missed your setClickable earlier, just tried this and it is working now. Thanks a lot, you are a genius...

Comment: Luis, this is definitely a bug in the sdk, before the animation just setting the visibility to INVISIBLE is all that it takes to skip the events. Thanks again